# Flutter “Share a Post” or “Direct / Private Message” (It’s already developed by LinkedIn, Twitter, and Facebook)

Tags: flutter, dart

When the user selects text / image and shares something via LinkedIn it asks for 2 options

```
(1). Direct / Private message (2). Share a Post
```

**How can I develop these features via the Flutter Mobile app?**

You can try this below step for a better understanding,
1. Open Wikipedia
2. select the text and share the text via LinkedIn, Twitter, and Facebook app.
you can see what I need to develop (same as the screenshot)

[image]

Current:-
Already tried out this package, In this package, I got the share content / Image in the application.
but it's not asking for options (intent).
This package already tried:- [Receive Intent](https://pub.dev/packages/receive_intent)

Expect:-
How I can show the user 2 options displayed in a screenshot?

Comment: Use this Package: https://pub.dev/packages/social_share

Comment: it's a content share package. I want to develop "received content" features.
Please read the description again. 
thanks.